# Enabling CORS for Chrome/Firefox Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am building a web app to be locally hosted on a Kindle Fire HD 10, in an area (an open-air museum) that does not have internet access.

All files and libraries have been loaded onto the device, and I am using Firefox to access the app. The app consists of locally-hosted javascript files for a panorama Javascript library (https://pannellum.org/), images, css files and an `index.html` file.

I am able to successfully point to the `index.html` file on the Kindle Fire through the browser, and load the app. However, I am not able to load the panorama images, and receive this CORS-related error in the console:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///E:/The%20Pith/Consultancy%20Projects/Boscobel%20Photo%20Sphere/panoramas/introroom.jpg. (Reason: CORS request not http).`

I originally received this on desktop, but was able to change circumvent it by changing the `strict_origin_policy` setting on Firefox. But this does not seem possible on Firefox Android.

Is there a way that I can do this otherwise (perhaps through Javascript, or through the  of my HTML file?

**Update**: Based on Callum Morrisson's comments below, there does not seem to be an easy solution to this.

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what code I would post - do you mean the error message in the console?

Comment: Mostly how you include the assets that are failing to load.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is you're accessing a static html file (no server), and then using non-relative paths for media within the html. I have no idea about Kindle Fire, but I doubt setting up a web server on the device is an option. So your next best option is to use relative paths to the assets.

Comment: I am using relative paths for my own code, so I imagine (in this case) it's the javascript library (Pannellum) that is using non-relative paths to serve the panorama images?

Comment: Could be, how does the library know about your images? Are you passing a list somewhere that contains `E:` ? Or does anything in your code contain `E:` ?

Comment: No - the library runs off a `.js` file (which I haven't delved into): in my `index.html`, I define the panorama images as relative paths within a JSON, e.g. `"panorama": "panoramas/whiteroom.jpg",`

Comment: Aha! There is a `basePath` JSON configuration option - _'This specifies a base path to load the images from.'_ The 'panorama' option says this: _'Sets the URL to the equirectangular panorama image. This is relative to basePath if it is set, else it is relative to the location of pannellum.htm. An absolute URL can also be used.'_ So how would I point to my locally-hosted folder as the root for `basePath`?

Comment: I've done a bit more digging, it looks like you're probably not doing anything wrong, modern browsers have made it needlessly difficult to access assets from javascript without a webserver. Best I can do is upvote your question and hope someone else knows of a hack that can get the image data into your page so the library can use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help - very frustrating!

Comment: I found a way: `const img = new Image();` then `img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...";` now pass the image to the constructor: `viewer = pannellum.viewer('container', { "panorama": img });` https://i.imgur.com/9qN0tdZ.png

Comment: Thanks so much - so if my image was stored at `panoramas/entrance.jpg`, how would I define that `src` attribute? @ChrisG

Comment: You need to convert the file into a base64 string and paste it in place of the ellipses: https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72649676/how-do-i-set-permissions-to-open-a-local-file-in-a-browser-on-an-android-12-phon/76199132#76199132 last time used special FF.