# How do I set permissions to open a local file in a browser on an Android 12 phone?

Tags: android, google-chrome, file-permissions

How do I set permissions to open a local file in a browser on an Android 12 phone?

My daughter has a Google Pixel 5/Fi phone and I also have an Android phone.

On previous Android releases (e.g. 9) you could let Chrome open local files by going into Settings>Apps>Chrome>Permissions> and selecting "Storage".

In Android 12, if you go into Settings>Apps>Chrome>Permissions> the item is now called "Files And Media" and has 3 options:

Allow Management of All Files

Allow Access to Media Only

Don't Allow

The first option does what I want, just like the old "Storage" option in Android 9.

EXCEPT that this option is NOT on the list for Chrome (or any other browser).  Is there some higher level switch somewhere like:  "Allow Browsers to access All Files"?

I'm guessing this is some sort of sandbox protection that most people would want to default to "Allow Access to Media Only".  However I DO want Chrome to access local Files.

I can also reproduce this on my Samsung phone, but as my daughter's Pixel phone (Pixel 5/Google Fi/Build SP2A.220505.002) is entirely a Google stack, I thought I'd point it out with that one to show this isn't some other vendor's issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was quite simple solution in FF.
But does not work in standard nor Nightly Play build now.

But was able to reuse few years old HTM page working with local files in FF:

- working FF version `fennec-68.11.0.multi.android-arm.apk` found here  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1300966 resp. https://download.mozilla.org/?product=fennec-latest&os=android&lang=multi
- and magic setting here (available in Nightly builds nowadays)
  `about:config`
  `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`
  True -> False
  (found here https://dev.to/dengel29/loading-local-files-in-firefox-and-chrome-m9f)

And known bin files in current folder are load again by same old simple AJAX.

```js
function load(n) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", n + ".bin", true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    oReq.onloadend = function (oEvent) {
        var arrayBuffer = oReq.response;
        if (arrayBuffer) {
            bufs.push(arrayBuffer);
        }
        if(bufs.length == sl) {
            var any = false;
            for(var b in bufs) {
                if(bufs[b].byteLength) {
                    any = true;
                    process(bufs[b], pos);
                    delete bufs[b];
                }
            }
            if(any) ...
        }
    }
    oReq.send();
}
```